# How to Importing gdb file into PostGIS using ogr2ogr in JS

Tags: ogr2ogr, node-js

I use ogr2ogr in nodeJS , my code is here :

```
ogr2ogr('D:/xxx.gdb', 
    {format: 'PostgreSQL',
  options: [
    "destination", `PG:'host=xxxxx port=5432 user=postgres password=xxxx
dbname=postgres'`,
  ] })
```

but I got error :
PostgreSQL driver doesn't currently support database creation.
Please create database with the `createdb' command.

how can I do this job ?